# MvvmCross Plugin Loading Issue in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I develop a Custom Plugin of MvvmCross for Windows Phone 8.1 and iOS

Its loading in iOS project but giving error in Windows Phone 8.1 at the **manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded();**

```
public class PluginLoader : IMvxPluginLoader
    {
        public static readonly PluginLoader Instance = new PluginLoader();
        public void EnsureLoaded()
        {
            var manager = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
            manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
        }
    }
```

**Error is**

> An exception of type 'Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException'
>   occurred in Cirrious.CrossCore.DLL but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: could not load plugin assembly for type
>   Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.PluginLoader

I am loading my Plugin in Windows Phone 8.1 using the following code

```
  public class TimerPluginBootstrap : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.PluginLoader>
        {
        }
```

I am Using **Windows Phone 8.1** and **MvvmCross 3.2.1** and Following are the more info

**Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer(Portable)**

ITimer.cs

```
public interface ITimer
    {
        void Start();
        void Stop();
        Action CallBackMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

PluginLoader.cs

```
public class PluginLoader : IMvxPluginLoader
    {
        public static readonly PluginLoader Instance = new PluginLoader();
        public void EnsureLoaded()
        {
            var manager = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
            manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
        }
    }
```

**Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.WindowsPhone**

MvxWindowsPhoneTimer.cs

```
public class MvxWindowsPhoneTimer : ITimer
    {
        private readonly DispatcherTimer timer;
        public MvxWindowsPhoneTimer(double kronosApiRecallTimeInMinutes)
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            Timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(kronosApiRecallTimeInMinutes);
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        }
        void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            CallBackMethod.Invoke();
        }
        public DispatcherTimer Timer
        {
            get { return timer; }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            Timer.Start();
        }
        public  void Stop()
        {
            Timer.Stop();
        }

        public Action CallBackMethod { get; set; }
    }
```

Plugin.cs

```
public class Plugin : IMvxPlugin
    {
        public void Load()
        {
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ITimer>(new MvxWindowsPhoneTimer(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update the question with any more trace, or any more info on what you've named your plugin assemblies? Also, can you clarify whether you mean Silverlight WinPhone 8.1 or Jupiter/Xaml WinPhone 8.1 (blame MS for the naming confusion!)

Comment: @Stuart If i not used TimerPluginBootsrap for Plugin Loading and Just resolve the Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ITimer>(new MvxWindowsPhoneTimer(1)); in my WindowsPhone 8.1 setup.cs class it will works fine

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean Silverlight WinPhone 8.1 or Jupiter/Xaml WinPhone 8.1 (blame MS for the naming confusion!)

Comment: Its WinPhone 8.1 its not Sliverlight WinPhone 8.1

Answer (score 1):

The plugin extension name for Silverlight is `WindowsPhone`

For Jupiter Xaml Windows Phone apps, the extension name is `WindowsCommon` (if shared with Win81) and `WindowsPhoneStore` for Store only.

---

So `Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.WindowsPhone.dll` is for Silverlight

And `Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.WindowsPhoneStore.dll` is for Jupiter Xaml apps

Comment: I checked by renaming my project as Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.WindowsPhoneStore.dll and Confiz.MvvmCross.Plugins.Timer.WindowsCommon .dll

But its not loading